# query doesn't return proper value

Tags: cakephp, mysqli

I have a query as given below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(FldStrategyID), FldTradeServerName,FldBaseDir,FldBinaryStartTime
FROM TblOrders Ord,
  (SELECT CONCAT(FldStrategyID,'.',FldTradeServerName,'.',FldBaseDir,'.',FldBinaryStartTime) strid
   FROM TblOrders
   GROUP BY FldStrategyID) as OrderView
WHERE Ord.FldStrategyID !=''
  AND OrderView.strid NOT IN (SELECT FldStrategyID FROM TblStrategyMasters WHERE 1)
```

The problem is that this part is not working:

```
OrderView.strid NOT IN (SELECT FldStrategyID FROM TblStrategyMasters WHERE 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the quotes(') are missing somewhere.

Comment: No error was given...if (') is missing there then it will give an error..but there has no error..